# How to fire onComplete function while using node-cron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cron

I'm using [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) to fire a function when the job runs (`onTick`) and fire a function when the job stops (`onComplete`); however, I'm not getting the expected behavior.

If the job actually runs then `onComplete` never runs:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var someDate = new Date('July 11, 2016 20:44:20');
var timeZone = 'America/Los_Angeles'

var job = new CronJob(someDate, function() {
        /* runs once at the specified date. */
        console.log("job running")
    }, function() {
        /* This function is executed when the job stops */
        console.log("job stopping")
    },
    true, /* Start the job right now */
    timeZone /* Time zone of this job. */
);
```

output:

```
hello-node-cron ❯ node date-usage.js
job running
```

But strangely if the date has already passed then `onComplete` will run:

output:

```
hello-node-cron ❯ node date-usage.js
job stopping
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Intuition aside, based on [one](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron/blob/master/tests/test-cron.js#L267) of its test cases, `onComplete` is triggered by a call to the `stop` API by design.

```
var job = new CronJob(someDate, function() {
        /* runs once at the specified date. */
        console.log("job running")
        this.stop() // <===================================== Add stop here.
    }, function() {
        /* This function is executed when the job stops */
        console.log("job stopping")
    },
    true, /* Start the job right now */
    timeZone /* Time zone of this job. */
);
```